# My headset has a jack for both speaker and microphone. My laptop has a single headset jack input. How can I record sound from my headset?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

My headset has a jack for both speaker and microphone. My laptop has a single headset jack input. How can I record sound from my headset?

When I plug the speaker in, I can hear sounds. When I plug the mic in, I can't hear sounds for obvious reasons, however Ubuntu seems to treat it as if it were speakers instead of a microphone. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You mean [stuff like this](https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-headsets-separate-headphone-microphone/dp/B004SP0WAQ)? Not really related to software though. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yeah you got the right idea, and that would be nice if I owned that converter, but I do not. All I have is the male mic jack and the male headphone jack.

Comment: There's no way around it with software. It's all about the plug and internal contacts. By design, headphones only work, just like in your typical phone or tablet, microphones only can't. If you want to use a mic only or headphones+mic you need the adapter mentioned above.

Comment: You can easily resolve this issue by purchasing an inexpensive  [USB headset](https://www.amazon.com/iMicro-IM320-USB-Headset/dp/B003RRY8ZG/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1489582371&sr=8-2&keywords=usb%2Bheadset%2Bwith%2Bmicrophone&th=1) assuming of course yout laptop has an available USB port.

Comment: Possible candidate for http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's a hardware question more likely to get traction on http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Akiva, assuming it could be solved via software (I doubt it) the value of your time you would spend in doing that would probably cost more than the few bucks/euros/whatever required for the adapter. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto More fun this way though~

Comment: Same problem here. In Windows it recognize my headset with an integrated microphone => on linux I can only use the speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a software issue, it's a hardware incompatibility issue. You see, your headset has a 3-contact plug, and your computer has a 4-contact socket. This can only be fixed by:

- Buying an adapter from 3-contact (earphones) + 2-contact (microphone) plug to 4-contact (earphones + microphone) plug.

or

- Buying a headset that has a 4-contact plug.

Comment: I don't think you can fix it by buying a different headset.  The jack is the problem, not the connector on the headset.  The 3.5mm connector is mechanically compatible to each 3.5mm jack but variations will make them electronically incompatible.

Comment: @bc2946088 Of course it can be fixed by buying a different headset. [USB ring a bell?](https://www.amazon.com/iMicro-IM320-USB-Headset/dp/B003RRY8ZG/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1489582371&sr=8-2&keywords=usb%2Bheadset%2Bwith%2Bmicrophone&th=1)

Comment: Touché, @ElderGeek.